# Issue in viewscope

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using primefaces 3.1

Tabview with dynamic = true is not working with viewscope.

On tabchange, it does not load data. But, if I change the view to sessionScope it loads the data.

Is there any way to use viewscope with dynamic = true.

Thanks,
Shikha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think is because the with view scope jsf is creating the bean again try putting

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PARTIAL_STATE_SAVING</param-name>
    <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Think it will do the trick.

Comment: 2.1.8-SNAPSHOT version of glassfish & the above solve the problem :)